# dynamic data to excel servlet

Tags: java, excel, servlets

I have a simple page where I am trying to pass the values to servlet which can write in excel.

When I get the value which is passed using `request.getParameter(value)` and use `system.out.println(value)` it prints the passed value.

When I try to write `value` in excel it writes blank, but when I write a `string` it writes the exact `string`. Have no idea whats going on. Need help.

Below is the script :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#getFile').click(function () {
                console.log( $('#test').val());
                $.get('excelCreaterServlet', {name: $('#test').val()}, function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    window.open("excelCreaterServlet");

                });

            });
        });
```

And below is the servlet code :

```
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(name);

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
    HSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(name);
    cell1.setCellValue("teest");



    ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wb.write(outByteStream);
    byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
    response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
    response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
    response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testxls.xls");
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(outArray);
    outStream.flush();
```

Comment: Does the "name" string have any whitespace around? This looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: nope, when i print it its printing the proper value but its not writing in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you are calling your servlet twice in below code :

```
    $.get('excelCreaterServlet', 
          {name: $('#test').val()}, 
          function (response) 
          {
              console.log(response);
              window.open("excelCreaterServlet");
          });
```

Once during **get** and another time during **window.open** without name parameter, which resulting your final output to null.

The solution is to use the following code which should work fine :

```
    window.open("excelCreaterServlet?name="+$('#test').val());
```